# Problems writing to a text file

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a report to a text file. When I use the `print` method everything appears okay but in the file nothing is written. Here is my code.

```
public void writeFile(String filename,String report){
    try{
        FileWriter fw=null;
        try{
            fw = new FileWriter(filename);
            fw.write("The game report \n");
            fw.write(report);
            fw.write("Hope everyone has enjoyed it");
            fw.flush();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println(filename +"not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        finally{
            try{
                fw.close();
            }
            catch( Exception exp){
                System.out.println("Problem closing the filewriter");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }   
}
```

And here is the code from the main method.

```
public class MainDarts {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameManager manager = new GameManager();
        manager.readFile("Data.csv");
        manager.Execute();
        String report = manager.getOverallReport();
        manager.writeFile("OutputData.txt", report);

    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried debugging?

Comment: If your code is not working it should be something related to GameManager. The other code is working as you expected.

Comment: I tried debugging but i dont understand much. the writebuffer has null value all the time

Comment: ~ Wow, I never realized the `FileWriter(String fileName)` documentation is so empty. It doesn't state what happens when the file does/doesn't exist already.

Answer (score 1):

use PrintWriter class like this

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("filename.txt", "UTF-8");
writer.println("Hello");
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Comment: i edited the answer, you will find the output file in the main directory of your projet if you are using an IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse

Comment: so validate it hhhhhhhhhh :p

Comment: Dont forget to close() in finally block or use try-with-resources

Answer (score 0):

Or you can consider something simpler like

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(filename))) {
  writer.write(report);
}
```

or

```
Files.write(Paths.get(filename), report.getBytes());
```